# locationInView ignoring orientation

Tags: ios, ios4, opengl-es-2.0

the coordinates returned by uitouch's locationInView are ignoring device orientation -

I have a uiview that properly rotates, but locationInview always returns as if it is portrait...the view overrides layerClass and provides CAEAGLLayer but it is still a uiview

Is there something special I need to do? Or is it just standard practice to detect the orientation and manually adjust?

Thanks for any help/advice

Comment: I think you are trying to get the location of your UIView. That is touched. But somewhere it's super or super->superview is rotated. That's why you the locationInView returns the original location in view by ignoring it's transform.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a ViewController for your host view. That should get the locationInView method to return orientation specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The view from which you are trying to get the CGPoint value is actually not getting resized, even though it might be getting oriented. Check its frame values before and after resize by:

```
NSLog(@"Rect Of View = %@",[[NSRectValue valueWithCGRect:yourView.frame] debugDescription]);
```